# Pure CSS Slider with Navigation and without inputs tag

Tags: css, slider

Starting from this project on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/hw/pen/biEBz)

I need to modify it since I cannot use any kind of input tag:

I presume that no other tag has the `:checked` pseudo class, and therefore have to find another solution

Googleing I understood that solution is in the `:target` pseudo class but this project is quite complicated for my simple mind,

And although I "transformed" the `<input>` in `<labels>` and the  `:checked` in `:target`, "my" latest solution works but not fully:

Main issue I cannot fix is autoplay: how can I solve?

Thanks

Joe

Comment: here is an old example of mine  using `:target` : https://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/vqkgf  But still nowdays, the most solid way to build slidrers is javascript ;)

Comment: Hi GCyrillus, thanks for answering and for the example: I will use it to improve my project.
But have to solve the AutoPlay issue: how did you do it?
Your example seems requiring manual trigger to start moving...

My problem is that I can't use js/jQuery and neither <form> related tags.

Comment: Do you need to have the next and previous buttons?

Comment: Well, at present my solution has only images sliding with AutoPlay it works but is not optimized: requires a lot of work if changing number of slides: the target is to have one easier to mantain and add some extra features to be as much similar to jquery 's version: text, prev/next buttons, bullets and so on, but ANY improvement is welcomed

Comment: thanks for your time.