# Pure css tabs without radio button

Tags: css, tabs

I'm trying to adapt this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kangrian/zgF54/) to work without radio button since I cannot use any `<form>` related tags, and neither javascript!

I "transformed" the `<input type='radio'>` into `<a>` tags, and transform the `:checked` pseudo class into `:target`
as you can see in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZMWaV).

but it does not work :-(

And also solution I used to show first Tab is not usable

Can suggest what's wrong?

Thanks
Joe

Comment: Why can't you use any form related tags?

Comment: It's a constraint of the site :-(

Comment: CSS there uses relation of checked element (dynamic native html event). Without form related tag, it can probably be done only with javascript.

Comment: forgot to write that I cannot use javascript too!

Comment: Yeah i don't think there's a good way to get that working without radio buttons or checkboxes OR javascript. I made a fiddle for you but it's soooo hacky :D https://jsfiddle.net/VilleKoo/jy5xky8f/

Comment: @VilleKoo oh... that is actually pretty nice - just one downside is that it goes away when clicked elsewhere...

Comment: yes, it works..(although I've succeed to modify my example with :focus, but not with :target :-()
But still one issue: would need to have Tag1 visible without requiring to click: no way to achieve this, right?

Comment: are you referring to your codepen demo?

Comment: yes, if I modify using `:focus` it works.. 
[SEE HERE](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dvQwQd), while the version with `:target` [SEE HERE](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZMWaV)

does not.. but will check what's wrong..surely I left something somewhere..

Comment: Check my edited answer

Comment: Wow!, that's Magic!!! :-)
too much for my simple mind :-(

Comment: I would not take too much advantage.. but I have another similar problem, this time with a slider: 
if you have 5 minutes to take a look... [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43091849/pure-css-slider-with-navigation-and-without-inputs-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, using the :target pseudo-class we can achieve this.

EDIT: I added a wrapper div so you can use position absolute on the panels. This allows you to have the first panel open and switch between them.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.tab-container { 
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
}

.tab-container:first-child { display: block }

:target { display: block }



/* just for demo */

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#tab-1-container">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-2-container">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-3-container">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="tab-1-container" class="tab-container">
    Tab 1 content
  </div>

  <div id="tab-2-container" class="tab-container">
  Tab 2 content
  </div>

  <div id="tab-3-container" class="tab-container">
  Tab 3 content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is only if each tab content has the same height/width as the other contents. If you change the content, you will see that it does not look well because the previous tab content is visible.

Comment: @jimver04 yeah that's true,  but it wasn't in the question / requirements :)